# Compiler Error Message: BC30648: String constants must end with a double quote

Tags: c#, javascript

```
Headliner = "<script language=""JavaScript1.2"" src=""stm31.js"" type=""text/javascript""></script>"
```

> This above line gives the error Compiler **Error Message: BC30648: String constants must end with a double quote**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If this is C#, put '@' before the string. Not sure why you have regex and C++ tags.

Comment: oops, Sorry i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would escape quotes in a string using a backslash (the standard escape character)...

```
Headliner = "<script language=\"JavaScript1.2\"...
```

If you want to escape them with another quote then use an `@` symbol at the start, which denotes a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)...

```
Headliner = @"<script language=""JavaScript1.2"" src=""stm31.js"" type=""text/javascript""></script>"
```

This method is typically used for strings that need to contain backslashes (without having to escape them) and not contain other escape characters (for example, `\t` for tab)

**NOTE**: I am assuming you are using C# here (because of the error code). You have also tagged javascript so you should really clarify which it is

Comment: Am not escape them with another quote. That code is a same line

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
  var Headliner
  = "<script language='JavaScript1.2' src='stm31.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
```

that's the way we follow when to render html from code behind. It is less complex because it is covered by lots of inverted commas.